# On $\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q)} \geq \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q)} \geq \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q} \geq \frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q)}$ where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $N=q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently Sorli conjectured that $k=1$ always holds.

Denote the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)$, the *deficiency* of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$, the *aliquot sum* of $x$ by $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$, and the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

Since $N=q^k n^2$ is perfect and $\gcd(q,n)=1$, we obtain
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(N)=2N=2q^k n^2.$$
Now using the fact that $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k))=1$, we see that $q^k$ must divide $\sigma(n^2)$, so that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}.$$
Now, using the identity
$$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{C-A}{D-B},$$
where $B \neq 0$, $D \neq 0$, and $D-B \neq 0$, then we obtain
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)}.$$

We now prove the following:

> **CLAIM:** If $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then the series of inequalities
> $$\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q)} \geq \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q)} \geq \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q} \geq \frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q)}$$
> holds in general.

**PROOF:** We prove each inequality one by one, left to right.

First, assume to the contrary that
$$2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)=D(n^2)=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q)} < \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q)} = \frac{2n^2}{q+1}.$$
This inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac{2q}{q+1}=2 - \frac{2}{q+1} < \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2} = I(n^2),$$
contradicting $I(n^2) \leq 2q/(q+1)$.

Next, suppose to the contrary that
$$\frac{2n^2}{q+1}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q)} < \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}.$$
This inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac{2q}{q+1} < \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2} = I(n^2),$$
contradicting $I(n^2) \leq 2q/(q+1)$.

Lastly, assume to the contrary that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q} < \frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q)} = \frac{2(\sigma(n^2) - n^2)}{q - 1}.$$
This inequality is equivalent to
$$(q - 1)\sigma(n^2) < 2q\sigma(n^2) - 2qn^2 \iff 2qn^2 < (q+1)\sigma(n^2) \iff \frac{2q}{q+1} < I(n^2),$$
contradicting $I(n^2) \leq 2q/(q+1)$.

Now here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Note that equality holds in
> $$\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q)} \geq \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q)} \geq \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q} \geq \frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q)}$$
> if and only if $k=1$.
> So do we have
> $$k=1 \iff \bigg(\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q)}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q)}=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}=\frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q)}\bigg) \iff \bigg(\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)}\bigg),$$
> by treating $k$ as a placeholder for $1$?
> If so, do we then have a proof for $k=1$, since
> $$\bigg(\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)}\bigg)$$
> holds unconditionally?

Comment: I think we don't. To see this, let us consider a claim that if $a^bc$ is a perfect number where $a,c$ are distinct primes and $b$ is a positive integer, then $b=1\iff$ $\bigg(\dfrac{D(c)}{s(a)}=\dfrac{2c}{\sigma(a)}=\dfrac{\sigma(c)}{a}=\dfrac{2s(c)}{D(a)}\bigg)$ $\iff$ $\bigg(\dfrac{D(c)}{s(a^b)}=\dfrac{2c}{\sigma(a^b)}=\dfrac{\sigma(c)}{a^b}=\dfrac{2s(c)}{D(a^b)}\bigg)$. This claim is obviously false. Now, suppose that your idea works. Then we can prove, using your idea, that the above claim is true, which contradicts the fact that it is false. So, we see that your idea does not work.

Comment: I apologize, @mathlove, but I do not see why that claim is *obviously* false.

Comment: Note that you have restricted $a$ and $c$ to be *distinct* primes, which basically means that $a^b c$ is an *even* perfect number.

Comment: Nonetheless, the biconditionals still hold for an *even* perfect number, since we know that *trivially*, the Mersenne prime factor has exponent $1$.

Comment: Additionally, the formula
$$\frac{D(c)}{s(a^b)}=\frac{2c}{\sigma(a^b)}=\frac{\sigma(c)}{a^b}=\frac{2s(c)}{D(a^b)}$$
still holds when $a^b c$ is an *even* perfect number (i.e. when $a$ and $c$ are *distinct* primes).

Comment: Ohh no.  Looking again at your claim, @mathlove:  A perfect number cannot definitely be of the form $a^b c$ where $a$ and $c$ are distinct primes **if** $b=1$.  So your premise is flawed.

Comment: Eulerian form (OPN): $q^k n^2$.  Euclidean form (EPN): $6 \neq 2^{p-1} (2^p - 1)$.  So every perfect number (except $6$) is *not* squarefree.

Comment: $(a,b,c)=(2,2,7)$ is a counterexample. If we suppose that your idea works, then we can prove that the claim is true as follows : "Note that equality holds in $\dfrac{D(c)}{s(a)}\ge\dfrac{2c}{\sigma(a)}\ge\dfrac{\sigma(c)}{a}\ge\dfrac{2s(c)}{D(a)}$ if and only if $b=1$. So we have $b=1 \iff$ $\bigg(\dfrac{D(c)}{s(a)}=\dfrac{2c}{\sigma(a)}=\dfrac{\sigma(c)}{a}=\dfrac{2s(c)}{D(a)}\bigg)$ $\iff$ $\bigg(\dfrac{D(c)}{s(a^b)}=\dfrac{2c}{\sigma(a^b)}=\dfrac{\sigma(c)}{a^b}=\dfrac{2s(c)}{D(a^b)}\bigg)$ by treating $b$ as a placeholder for $1$." This means that your idea doesn't work.

Comment: Reading your comments, I think that you don't get my point. I deliberately chose $a^bc$, and I know that it is not an odd perfect number. Moreover, I know that the claim is false. I wrote the claim to explain why your idea does not work. Also, the premise is not flawed. (Note that $b=1$ is written after "then". The claim says that "if $a^bc$ is a perfect number, then $b=1$ is equivalent to...". The claim does not say that "if $a^bc$ is a perfect number with $b=1$, then...".)

Comment: Is it not supposed to be the case that the Mersenne prime factor (*trivially*) has exponent $1$, @mathlove? What you simply have (which is not really a counterexample to my claim) is the second even perfect number $28$, which has Mersenne prime factor $2^3 - 1 = 7$. Nonetheless, I have double-checked and verified that my claim holds for *even* perfect numbers.

Comment: $(a,b,c)=(2,2,7)$ is a counterexample to *the claim I wrote*, not yours. So, I know that the claim I wrote is false. However, using your idea, one can prove that the claim I wrote is true. This means that you idea does not work.

Comment: In other words, what I am trying to say is that, to use your notation, $a^b$ should be the Mersenne prime factor.  (Otherwise, the formula would not hold.) Which means $b=1$. But your $c$ is prime, which contradicts my requirement that it has to be a square.

Comment: Therefore, I do not see how your claim being false would have anything to say about my claim. My claim is about odd perfect numbers.

Comment: Is there any error in the following? $$$$If $a^bc$ is a perfect number where $a,c$ are distinct primes and $b$ is a positive integer, then note that equality holds in
$$\frac{D(c)}{s(a)}\ge\frac{2c}{\sigma(a)}\ge\frac{\sigma(c)}{a}\ge\frac{2s(c)}{D(a)}$$
if and only if $b=1$. So we have$$b=1 \iff \bigg(\frac{D(c)}{s(a)}=\frac{2c}{\sigma(a)}=\frac{\sigma(c)}{a}=\frac{2s(c)}{D(a)}\bigg) \iff \bigg(\frac{D(c)}{s(a^b)}=\frac{2c}{\sigma(a^b)}=\frac{\sigma(c)}{a^b}=\frac{2s(c)}{D(a^b)}\bigg)$$by treating $b$ as a placeholder for $1$.

Comment: It obviously would not work for your counterexample, @mathlove, because it does not satisfy the constraints of my problem. But I still do **not** see your point. What exactly is it?

Comment: Your purported $c$ has to be a **square**.

Comment: I know that it does not satisfy the constraints of your problem. Just forget the constraints and the knowledge about even perfect numbers temporarily, and read the sentences just as written. Do you see any error in the logic?

Comment: See my answer. "But I still do not see your point. What exactly is it?" My point is that treating $k$ as a placeholder for $1$ does not work.

Comment: It is very difficult for me to explain your mistake to you. Maybe someone can do in a better way. What I'm saying is that it is wrong that $$\bigg(\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q)}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q)}=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}=\frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q)}\bigg) \iff \bigg(\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)}\bigg)$$

Answer (score 0):

(**This is a partial answer, mainly for my own benefit.**)

Let $q^k n^2$ be an *odd perfect number* with special prime $q$.

Assume to the contrary that $k \neq 1$.

Then we obtain the following chain of inequalities and equations
$$\dfrac{D(n^2)}{s(q)} > \dfrac{2n^2}{\sigma(q)} > \dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q} > \dfrac{2s(n^2)}{D(q)} > \dfrac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)} = \dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \dfrac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} = \dfrac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)},$$
which does **not** result in a contradiction.